# best way to send email in asp net c# MVC with attachment between Thread or Async

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to know the best way for sending emails with attachment between Thread OR Async in ASP.net MVC C#.
OR 
Do I need to use other library for sending email with attachments.

If someone provide sample working code. It would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using(var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    var message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.body = "body text";
    message.subject = "subject text";
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("path to file"));
    await client.SendAsync(message);
}
```

Comment: Here in Async means SendAsync(MailMessage).

Comment: Aha, made changes to my answer.

Comment: since you are not `await`ing this will either a) run synchronously if the containing method isn't marked `async` or b) run a fire-and-forget that runs the risk of being murdered by ASP without warning or notice of failure or having an exception thrown by the `SmtpClient` that you won't be notified about.

Comment: Completely right! Accidentally left out the `await`!